# Runtime equivalent to #if UNITY_ANDROID

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

In Unity, I am familiar with using `#if` statements to run platform-dependent code. However, I need a runtime evaluation of the player. I know of the `Application.platform` enum, from solution [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/604503/if-unity-editor-stuff-getting-called-at-runtime-as.html).

However, you must be actually running on the actual device for this to run. In the Unity editor, `#if UNITY_ANDROID` still compiles if your editor is set to build to Android. Is there a runtime equivalent to `#if UNITY_ANDROID`?

Using `Application.isEditor || Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android` would work, but I don't want this to be true if I am building to PC in the editor.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found it after a some more digging.

```
EditorUserBuildSettings.activeBuildTarget
```

Leaving this here as a service to those with the same question.

*** EDIT ***

Comment by Programmer is correct. Editor libraries only compile if you are in the Unity Editor, not building for device. I suppose the equivalent would be initializing a bool wrapped in an `#if UNITY_ANDROID` then using that bool at runtime.

Comment: This is wrong. This is for the Editor only. `Application.platform` is the only solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is:

```
#if PLATFORM_ANDROID
    // code for android
#endif
```